# Error Message: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, quality-filter

How do you solve the following error when creating a simple post?

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details

Answer (score 20):

The answer is in the error message: add more details.

- What are you trying to achieve
- what are you expecting to get out
- What *did* you get out (include error messages)
- What else have you tried?
- What do you think is causing it?
- Why do you need to make a new question for it?  Why is your problem different to other, similar questions on here?