# Error while pasting CODE in code block

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to put my code in an edit while asking a question.

I'm getting this error:

> It looks like your post is mostly code please add more Detail

I checked [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184921/stackoverflow-error-message-it-looks-like-your-post-is-mostly-code-please-add) to improve the code but unfortunately the error is not solved.

Is there a way to directly adjust  the indent of the code so that I can paste code directly?