# How does this question not meet your quality standards?

Tags: support, asking-questions, quality-filter

> given an array of objects that have an attribute count and an index n, how can objects after n be removed if their count is 0?

Please explain what is lacking in this question?

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Exchange :) Did you post this question on any of the Stack Exchange network sites? Kindly consider [editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/329791/edit) this post and share a link to the  question.

Comment: On which site did you post this?

Comment: This is off topic here. Please ask this question in the per-site meta of the site where you posted the question that did not meet the quality standards.

Comment: Did you by any chance entered that question with the code formatting that I now removed? Did the error message also mentioned that your question looked like code? For example as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184921/error-message-it-looks-like-your-post-is-mostly-code-please-add-some-more-deta)?

Comment: People are willing to help you answer your homework questions, but you can't just pass them onto us and expect us to do it for you. You must attempt to solve them yourself and, along the way, if you reach a point beyond which you cannot move ask about that point and how to overcome it. If you can't get anywhere at all, you need to go to your instructor. You're paying them to teach you.

Answer (score 18):

Well ... **everything**?

- Is this a programming problem?
- If so, which language are you using?
- What have you tried to solve the problem?
- Where are you stuck?

<sub>(Right now, which site did you post this question on, but that's not a deficit of your original question.)</sub>

Stack Exchange is full of smart people, but they don't have a crystal ball, nor can they read minds. You have to provide more details, otherwise we can't help you.